# Why do the doors in the Electrical Room change?

Tags: among-us

On the Airship, why do the doors in the Electrical Room change their order?
It is annoying to navigate through it especially if you are an imposter and you are running away from the body.

It's also a danger if we get stuck in a dead end in the electrical room when an imposter is chasing you!

[image: Image of closed door next to the electrical room]

Comment: Hello! Just an FYI, we prefer to have questions asking only one question at a time.

Comment: Ok I thought the question would be kinda small so I added some more.

Comment: If you want a good question also I would say add details. Like how are the doors changing, or a screenshot of what doors you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is annoying to navigate through it especially if you are an imposter and you are running away from the body.

> It's also a danger if we get stuck in a dead end in the electrical room when an imposter is chasing you!

Why, you answered your own question! To add spice to the game, forcing you to solve the puzzle every time you want to cross the area. Same as 'decontamination' on Polus, same as the lengthy corridor to the reactor on Mira, or airship's hoverboard - a part of level design that disrupts standard motion, and makes a difference in a chase where normally players move at the same speed.